# Switched to JBoss Wildfly 9 and now I get a null principal object when I log in to my Spring web application

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-security, wildfly, principal

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE, and have just moved to JBoss Wildfly 9.0.0.CR2 from JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  In the new JBoss environment, every time I login to my web application, the Principal object is null.  The same codebase on JBoss 7.1.3.Final has no issues.  The relevant part of the stack trace is

```
[DEBUG,ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String org.mainco.subco.myproject.mvc.LoginController.authenticate(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[DEBUG,DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String org.mainco.subco.myproject.mvc.LoginController.authenticate(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[DEBUG,DispatcherServlet] Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'activity/response/file'; model is {error={"status":"failure","exception":"NullPointerException"}}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.mvc.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:253)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

I have this spring security http element …

```
<beans:bean id="subcoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.mainco.subco.core.security.subcoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure" />
            <beans:property name="exceptionMappings" ref="exceptionMappings" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/authenticate" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

<!--  This allows us to redirect to different URLs based on various authentication
      exceptions.  This gives us the ability to customize error messages. -->
<util:map id="exceptionMappings">
    <beans:entry key="org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException" value="/login/expired" />
</util:map>

<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="subcoSecurityContextRepository"
    class="org.mainco.subco.core.security.subcoSecurityContextRepository" />

<http pattern="/activities/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/audio/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/bootstrap/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/bootstrap-editable/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/temp/**" security="none" /> 

<http name="defaultSecurity" security-context-repository-ref="subcoSecurityContextRepository"
    auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    access-denied-page="/denied" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
        ref="subcoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/lti/launch" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/status" access="permitAll" />
    …
    <intercept-url pattern="/dwrsetcookie" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/dwrpageid" access="permitAll" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" id="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Through debugging, I can see that in my “UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)” method, a valid, non-null object is getting returned.  But yet when the "authenticationSuccessHandler" is invoked

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate")
public String authenticate(final HttpServletRequest request,
                           final Principal principal)
{
    final subcoAuthenticationUser sbUser = (subcoAuthenticationUser) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
```

The “principal” object is null.  How can I start troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to switch spring logs to debug and then tried .. That helps usually ..

Comment: That's what I did.  See how my log contains the word "DEBUG" at the beginning?